# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Верно ли расставлены тут знаки препинания: "Ехать еще было далеко — старенький автобус мелко подпрыгивал на брусчатке — поэтому он решительно вытащил из кармана джинсов мобильный телефон..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение со вставной конструкцией. (Подробный ответ есть в следующем вопросе). Перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения. Пример у РОзенталя: **Смеялся он мало — настолько у него хватало чувства такта, — но всё же насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах — вторая часть начинается с союза, перед которым должна быть запятая**. Получается так: "Ехать еще было далеко — старенький автобус мелко подпрыгивал на брусчатке, — поэтому он решительно вытащил из кармана джинсов мобильный телефон..."

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, лучше оформить так: *"Старенький автобус мелко подпрыгивал на брусчатке. Ехать еще было далеко, поэтому он решительно вытащил из кармана джинсов мобильный телефон..."* 
Но если уж хочется именно такое последовательности, то вот:
Очевидно, часть, начинающаяся с *"поэтому"* относится к *"ехать было ещё далеко"*, а то, что посередине является каким-то мудреным попутным замечанием. Можно, конечно, выделить и тире, но я бы взял такое в скобочки.
Я не знаю, нужна ли запятая после *"на брусчатке"*, если поставить тире.